# Visual Studio Code + Java - doesn't find my dependencies from build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code doesn't resolve dependencies declared in my `build.gradle.kts` file in this [test project](https://github.com/pmorch/stackoverflow-vscode-gradle-test). Can you help me see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using the newest VScode (downloaded 1.52.1 yesterday), and I've started from a clean install by deleting `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode` before starting VScode.

When opening up my Java file and installing various suggested extensions (see below), I end up seeing `The import org.keycloak cannot be resolved`:

[image: error with dependencies]

which is true for any dependencies from `build.gradle.kts`. Notice how `java.util.List` is fine.

`gradle` builds the project fine, even from within VScode:

[image: gradle builds fine]

Also, "Java Projects" shows "Referenced Libraries" as empty:

[image: Referenced Libraries empty]

I suspect that an empty "Referenced Libraries" is related to not resolving `org.keycloak` above.

The exact same project is fine when opened in Intellij.

I've used this [test project](https://github.com/pmorch/stackoverflow-vscode-gradle-test), and after installing various suggested extensions, I ended up with this list from `code --list-extensions`:

```
fwcd.kotlin
mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
naco-siren.gradle-language
redhat.java
richardwillis.vscode-gradle
richardwillis.vscode-gradle-extension-pack
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
```

Edit: I've tried following https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting. I looked at `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` where I didn't see anything obviously related to my problem, although I'm not sure what I was looking for. (I've saved the [log from developer tools](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmorch/stackoverflow-vscode-gradle-test/master/console.log), but warning: The saved file's formatting is not easy to read...) I also tried to run `Java: Clean the Java language server workspace` and that didn't help either.

Comment: what is `build.gradle.kts` file, and how is it different from `build.gradle` files? I've only seen the latter.

Comment: `build.gradle.kts` files are written in kotlin, while `build.gradle` files are written in groovy.  `gradle` understands `build.gradle.kts` files just fine. As you can see, it builds. Also, a fresh [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) kotlin project has a `build.gradle.kts` file and there VScode *can* resolve dependencies.

Comment: NOTE: My above comment suggests that a fresh Sping Initializr project works. I was wrong. It doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update on 8/26/2021

It's now supported! See: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/632#issuecomment-905715322

---

Gradle *.kts files are not supported right now, which means your project is not recognized correctly.

See: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/632

Comment: I was certain that I'd tried a fresh [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) kotlin project has a build.gradle.kts file and that there VScode *could* resolve dependencies. But I was wrong. That fails too, albeit for different reasons. It doesn't even get that far. It seems VScode for java is not ready yet for kotlin development.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch note that kotlin development in general and support for it in gradle build scripts are two different things. As far as I know, kotlin development in general works.

Comment: I'm sure that is true. We, however use build.gradle.kts in all our kotlin projects.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have fixed it by referencing the gradle cache folder in my settings.json.

[image: settings.json location]

```json
{
  "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "C:\\Users\\<UserName>\\.gradle\\caches\\**\\*.jar"
  ]
}
```